# I want to initialize a final variable into a function

Tags: java, final

Program code:

```
public class A{
   public static final String l;

   public void method(String strTestData){
     l = strTestData;
   }
}
```

strTestData will contain data like "public static final java.lang.String DELETE".
is it possible?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why an instance method is affecting a class variable (its not disallowed to do that, but it is unusual)

Comment: If you're trying to make a class that goes through an initial building state before use, consider using the *builder pattern* instead -- separate the builder part into a separate class. This lets you keep your final fields in the built class.

Answer (score 9):

This is not possible.

If you declare a `static final` field, it must be initialized in a static inializer or at the point of declaration. You cannot later modify the value. For example:

```
public static final String l = "Foo";
```

or

```
public static final String l;

static {
  l = "Bar";
}
```

Perhaps you should just remove the `final` modifier?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to initialize a final variable into a function

**NO**,You can't do this. This is in accordance with [JLS8.3.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2):

> **It is a compile-time error if a blank final (§4.12.4) class variable
>   is not definitely assigned (§16.8) by a static initializer (§8.7) of
>   the class in which it is declared.**
>
> A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned (§16.9) at
>   the end of every constructor (§8.8) of the class in which it is
>   declared; otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

Hence your code would look like this:

```
public class A{
   public static final String l;
   static
    {
       l = "Static String initialized..";
    }
}
```

Or, You can initialize final variable at the time of declaration as follows:

```
public static final String l = "Static String initialized..";
```

Answer (score 1):

If a variable is declared final, you can only initialize it once. In fact you need to initialize EXACTLY once. This has to happen either when you declare the member variable or in the constructor.

Trying to change it is also impossible.

Comment: The OP's variable is `static`, so it cannot be initialized in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize a `final` variable from a method. This is needed because the compiler needs to ensure that the variable is initialized only once.

A method can be called at any time and therefore the compiler cannot ensure that the variable is only initialized once.